# C# Form - Property Change

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form which has a `Property` named `Car` which is a class with several properties.

Depending on some user actions that **property** will be set to the current **car** being displayed.

So I meed want to know when that property is assigned or set to null.

I am aware of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` but in my case I'm not sure if it's applicable since I don't want to monitor my `Car` properties changing but the `Car` property itself.

Any ideas how to acomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the relevant code for the form and `car` class. You should be able to add `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the form.

Comment: That's right, It did not cross my mind :) Thanks

Comment: I think implementing INotifiyPropertyChanged is a fine idea. But if for some reason you didn't want to do that (it's marginally a little more trouble than the alternative), you could stick with the normal Forms paradigm, implementing a plain old "CarChanged" event. Then code that needs to know when the property value has changed can just subscribe to that specific event (INotifyPropertyChanged is more general purpose, which can be good, but it also means subscribers get notified for changes to _all_ properties, not just the one they care about).

Answer (score 0):

If you created a true property on your class, then you should have a getter and setter.
You can add code directly in the setter of the Form property to take action depending upon which "car" the value is set to:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Define the Car class
    public class Car 
    {
        public string Name = string.Empty;
    }

    // private variable to hold the current Car value
    private Car _car = null;

    // Public form property that you can run code when either the get or set is called
    public Car car
    {
        get
        {
            return _car;
        }
        set
        {
            _car = value;

            if (_car == null)
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Run code here when car is set to null", "Car is set to null");
            else
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Run code here: the cars name is: '" + _car.Name + "'", "Car is set to a value");
        }
    }
    private void SomeFunction()
    {
        Car MyCar = new Car();
        MyCar.Name = "HotRod";

        // This will fire the car setter property
        this.car = MyCar;
    }
}
```